# JavaScript for Google Analytics custom dimension

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

could someone assist me with making this code work please? I was given the following code GA snippet when I created a custom dimension of UserID:

```
var dimensionValue = 'SOME_DIMENSION_VALUE';
ga('set', 'dimension1', dimensionValue);
```

I want to include that snippet into the script below but I'm new to JavaScript coding. GA was previously set up on the site but I need to update it from classic to universal. The website I want statistics for is on Oracle WebCenter Interaction and the old GA code used the pt:common.userinfo adaptive tag to retrieve the current user's name.

Thanks in advance

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;    i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new  Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com   /analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  var dimensionValue = 'SOME_DIMENSION_VALUE';
  ga('set', 'UserID', <pt:common.userinfo pt:info="FullName"/>);
  ga('send', 'pageview'); 
</script>
```

Comment: Just add the lines before `ga('send', 'pageview');` and after `ga('set', 'UserID', <pt:common.userinfo pt:info="FullName"/>);`

Answer (score 0):

You can either set it like so:

```
// Set the user ID when creating the tracker.
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {'userId': 'as8eknlll'});
```

or

```
// Alternatively, you may set the user ID via the `set` method.
ga('set', 'userId', 'as8eknlll');

// followed by the pageview hit
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Cf. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference